# Getting a sticky background terminal running on the bspwm workspace in fullscreen

Tags: shell-script, startup, window-manager, daemon, bspwm

I am attempting to have a terminal running a custom command in the background layer of my window manager in full screen mode on boot.

attempted to execute in bspwmrc, but did not execute on boot

```
#!/bin/bash
termite -e "cava" --title=desktopconsole & sleep 0.3
wmctrl -r desktopconsole -b add,below,sticky
wmctrl -r desktopconsole -b add,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
```

executed in bspwmrc currently on boot.

```
termite -e "cava" --role=dc1; sleep 0.3; wmctrl -i -r "$(wmctrl -l | grep "cava" | tail -1 | cut -f1 -d' ')" -e 10,0,594,1920,500 &
```

Is this possible? I have not been able to find any useful examples.
With the one-liner, I have a terminal on my workspace executing the program when I log in. This is exactly what I want besides for adding sticky and moving the window to the background layer at all times. I have not had much luck with the layer attribute yet :P all insights are appreciated. thanks